# Use FileTable from Entity Framework 5.0 Designer?

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I would like to use a FileTable to store a bunch of data, as well as migrate a lot of file-based existing data.

I know that I can access the file stream property in a table if I create it- it's just varbinary(MAX) so Entity Framework 5.0 designer has no problems with those tables.  But I can't seem to get a SQL 2012 FileTable to show in my edmx designer.

The error I get is this:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The
>   table 'EpicDB.dbo.DataFileTable' is referenced by a relationship, but
>   cannot be found.

DataFileTable is the name of my FileTable.

In SQL Management Studio designer, I notice that the FileTable has an odd self-reference between path_locator and parent_path_locator.  Maybe this is generating some pain?

Anyone know how I can do this?